# How to draw a real time graph for proximity sensor in Android studio?

Tags: android

I want to draw a real time graph for proximity sensor is it possible. Im not a Professional

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GraphView graph1;
    private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> Series;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GraphView graph1 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.main_graph1);

        Series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
        graph1.addSeries(Series);
        Viewport viewport = graph.getViewport();
        viewport.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
        viewport.setMinY(0);
        viewport.setMaxY(10);
        viewport.setScrollable(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. This code will help you get the value of the sensor. Then, in `onSensorChanged` use `event.values[0]` to get the value, and draw it in any way you wish.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mProximity;
private static final int SENSOR_SENSITIVITY = 4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    /*if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
        if (event.values[0] >= -SENSOR_SENSITIVITY && event.values[0] <= SENSOR_SENSITIVITY) {
            //near
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "near", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //far
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

*** EDIT ***
In order to add the values to the graph, you should simply append the data to the series, something like:

```
series.appendData(new DataPoint(xPoint, lumValue), true, 1000);
```

You can look here for an example:
[RealTime chart](http://www.android-graphview.org/realtime-chart/) or [GraphView Realtime plot of Sensor Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687208/graphview-realtime-plot-of-sensor-data)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I using the same code as you but my problem is when i put my finger on sensor it shows near and when i remove my finger it shows far. I added a graph library to draw a real time graph. I'm developing an application to record photoplethysmography signal by using this sensor but I'm confused.

Comment: You problem is still unclear. What I understood is that you want the proximity values so you can put them on the graph, and I suggested the way to get them (using event.values[0] in onSensorChanged). If your problem is something else, please explain exactly what you need.

Comment: I think the proximity values must change every moment when i put  my finger on it due to the light changes but I don't know how to put real time light values on the graph.

Comment: OK, now your real problem is clear - I've updated my answer.